# Can I forward keyboard shortcuts to a lync conversation window docked in a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, docking, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

I am working with Lync 2013 SDK and WPF in a way to add a toolbar to the Lync conversation window.

I did dock the Lync conversation window in a panel inside a WindowFormHost pretty much following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/jj933086.aspx.

Now I can add my custom functionnality inside my WPF window.

The problem is that docking the conversation causes all Lync conversation window shortcuts to act in a strange way. By default, they don't work anymore, even if I try to focus the docked conversation window, they still don't work but when I focus a control of this window they start working all over again.

I need them working whatever is focused on in my WPF window or the docked Lync conversation window.

I tried to use some user32.dll functions to invoke those shortcuts using the conversation window handle IntPtr, but it did not work.

I also tried to use

```
SetForegroundWindow(_automation.GetConversationWindow(convertion).Handle)
```

and then use

```
SendKeys.SendWait(keys)
```

but it only work when the conversation is not docked.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue in a project I was working on.  I think the problem was that the shortcuts were being unregistered when the window was out of focus.  We had to re-register the shortcuts that were related to that window.  I'm not sure how your shortcuts are registered though.